# If/else statement with a triplet that sum to a given value

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm writing a sum up game where two players will take turns picking a random number in the range (1,9), no repeated number allowed. So I'm struggling at

> If at any point exactly three of the player's numbers sum to 15, then that player has won.

If the first player picks [7, 2, 3, 5], he will win because 7+3+5 = 15

So my question is why doesn't the program stop when first_player has inputs == 15

I want to avoid importing any libs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating all permutations at each step, maintain a map of what each permutation sums to, then add two branches to each branch at each move.

Think of each entry as a set of bits, ie with each permutation you either include a given entry or not, eg if the numbers are [7, 3, 2] you might store [1, 0, 1] for the combination of the 7 and the 2.

You can make a hashmap of 101->9 etc and when someone adds a 3 to it you add an entry for 1010->9 and 1011->12. As soon as you see the target you know the game is over.

So the evolution of [7, 3, 2] would be

```
0->0
1->7
00->0
01->3
10->7
11->10
000->0
001->2
010->3
011->5
100->7
101->9
110->10
111->12
```

Comment: Hello Carlos Thank you for the comment but this is Python for beginner, we are not allowed to use harshmap

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way would be to find only those numbers whose sum is equal to the `target` that is 15.

```
entry = [7, 5, 1, 3]

def is_sum_15(nums):
    res = []
    search_numbers(nums, 3, 15, 0, [], res)
    return len(res) != 0
    
def search_numbers(nums, k, n, index, path, res):
    if k < 0 or n < 0:
        return 
    if k == 0 and n == 0: 
        res.append(path)
    for i in range(index, len(nums)):
        search_numbers(nums, k-1, n-nums[i], i+1, path+[nums[i]], res)

print(is_sum_15(entry)) # True
```